# Is there such an expression in English, 'if not today, then tomorrow'?

Tags: phrase-request

Is there such an expression in English that means "not today, then tomorrow" ?

I wonder whether the Russian phrase "не сегодня, так завтра" (which translates exactly so and means "soon, eventually") has an equivalent in English.

Comment: I think "if not today, then tomorrow" is natural in English as well.

Comment: Could you provide an example of a situation when and how you would use this phrase? Are you literally predicting a resolution in the near future, or making a statement of satisfaction that the resolution will come in some indeterminate future time? Is this a statement of anticipation or resignation?

Comment: @choster Say, a prediction of near future (so the words 'today' and 'tomorrow' are not used literally)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- eventually
- any day now
- one day or another (see also [one way or another](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/one-way-or-another))
- sooner or later
- ultimately

and more distant ones

- someday
- one day

It mostly depends on what you are trying to emphasise. Is it the inevitability of the event? Or is it the imminence of that event?

We also have it in Ukrainian, but in English I find "eventually" and "sooner or later" to work best for me.

Answer (score 0):

Some more idiomatic phrases are

> Maybe not today, but soon.
>
> In a matter of days.
>
> Might not be tonight or tomorrow.
>
> One of these days.
>
> There's always tomorrow.